# How to configure command line git to use ssh key

Tags: git, authentication, command-line, github, ssh-keys

When I do `git pull` via the command line, it always asks for my github username and password.  I'd like to tell it to use the ssh key in github, and never have to worry about it again.  How do you do this?

Comment: You want Git to use your *client* SSL certificate? That would require letting the remote service, e.g. GitHub, knowing about your SSL certificate. You can get the "never have to worry about it again" experience by [using *SSH keys*](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) instead of HTTP, though. Note that you will have to change the remote so it uses `git@github...` instead of `https://...`.

Comment: Ah yeah, wrong terminology. I swear im not that big of a noob. Updated with proper info

Comment: And i do have a key in github, and integrated in my gui/ide

Comment: Then you can try just changing your remote and see if that works: assuming your remote is called `origin` and you've got a relatively recent Git, `git remote set-url origin git@github...` and `git remote set-url --push origin git@github...`. Get the `git@github...` part from GitHub by clicking on the SSH link for your clone URL. If that doesn't do it, you may have to (a) add a second key to GitHub, or (b) let your command-line `git` know about the key you're using in your IDE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming that you have used `ssh-keygen` to generate a key pair and uploaded the public key in the appropriate place in your github account, you should be able to set remote to use the url `git@github.com:username/repo.git`.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

If you do not have local changes that you care about, you can just delete your local repository and clone again:

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

Here are [github's instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) on this setup, which you can use as a reference as needed.

Comment: everywhere on the internet there are tutorials on how to copy the generated key into github account. but, your answer still doesn't include the answer on how to use the private. "now I created the private key, how does git knows where to get it from?"

Comment: @BinarWeb You're welcome to propose an edit. I think I may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 18):

To tell Git to use the key that you generated, add the following to your ssh config (on Linux, usually located at `~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

For the `IdentityFile` you should use the key that was generated by `ssh-keygen` (not the one whose name ends in `.pub`). The `User` [must always be `git`](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/error-permission-denied-publickey#always-use-the-git-user).

Comment: This was my issue. I was trying ssh-agent and other things, but this config file fixed it.

Comment: This should be the top answer, since it answers the question that everyone really has. How to use the local key, no one with the capability to google has to ask for how to paste a key into github.

Comment: This one worked for me! I named my key something different than the default `id_ed25519`, and it was passphrase-protected, so one/both of those two things made my Github key not be automatically added to the agent. Now, if I do something like `git pull`, it'll prompt me for the passphrase and then add the key to the agent! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Having looked at these answers, it seems the one I found easiest is not included.  In the working directory of the repo you are interested in specifying a specific key, do:

```bash
git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa'  #specific private key
```

You can check to see that it worked (or see if there is an existing `core.sshCommand` for the repo) by doing:

```bash
git config --list
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that after creating the ssh you may have moved the keys to a different folder. In that case,
`ssh-add ~/yourkeyfolder/yourkey`

This will ensure that your key is known to the os.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a **Gnome-based Linux desktop**, such as Ubuntu or Fedora, you can also use the built-in "*Passwords and encryption*" application to create and manage SSH keys. To create an SSH key, just open the application, click `+`, then `SSH Key`, fill out the form, enter the password for the key twice and finally insert the generated public key information into GitHub. After that, the `git` command will use this SSH key for SSH connections. You have to enter the password for the SSH key only once per session. In this case there is no need to configure `ssh-agent` or modify `~/.ssh/config`, it just works.